# Cannot get Canvas restore to work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, canvas

I cant get an example of the canvas save and restore to work on IE 11

After trying many times with my own code, I searched for an example online and even this one didnt work as expected

```
   function drawShape(){

        // get the canvas element using the DOM
        var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

        // Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
        if (canvas.getContext){

           // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
           var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

           // draw a rectangle with default settings
           ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);

           // Save the default state
           ctx.save();
           alert("Check Point 1");

           // Make changes to the settings
           ctx.fillStyle = '#66FFFF'
           ctx.fillRect( 15,15,120,120);

           alert("Check Point 2");

           // Make the new changes to the settings
           ctx.fillStyle = '#993333'
           ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
           ctx.fillRect(30,30,90,90);

           // Restore previous state
           ctx.restore();
           alert("Check Point 3");

           // Draw a rectangle with restored settings
           ctx.fillRect(45,45,60,60);

           // Restore original state
           ctx.restore();
           alert("Check Point 4");

           // Draw a rectangle with restored settings
           ctx.fillRect(40,40,90,90);
        } else {
           alert('You need Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this demo.');
        }
     }
```

I was expecting to see 2 rectangles ( one for the save and one last recangle ) however, I see all 5 rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need this:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clear = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clear || function(preserveTransform) {
    if (preserveTransform) {
        this.save();
        this.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    }

    this.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    if (preserveTransform) {
        this.restore();
    }
}
```

I am using it to animate stuff inside canvas and I am clearing and redrawing. This I do before each new draw.

Use it as follows:

ctx.clear() // ctx = canvas -> 2dcontext

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following sample code, it works well on my side(using IE 11.116.18362.0 version):

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    function init() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillStyle = '#FA6900';
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 4;
        ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5)';
        // Save the default state
        ctx.save();

        //draw a rectangle 
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

        // Restore the default state
        ctx.restore();

        ctx.fillRect(150, 40, 100, 100);

    }

    init();
</script>
```

the result like this:

[image]

More detail information about canvas save and restore, please check this article: [Understanding save() and restore() for the Canvas Context](https://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/)

Comment: Looking at the result - I actually see two squares, one green and the other orange - is this what you are seeing ? as I believe that I should only be seeing the orange square

Comment: The orange rectangle is the saved default state, and the green rectangle is the rectangle we draw after save the default state. After calling the restore method, it will using the default state.